# What are my obligations towards my adviser after the defense, revisions, and all forms signing is done?

Tags: phd, advisor

Just few days ago, I completed all requirements for the degree, all is set and done. I am organizing a workshop with my adviser to be held in few months. Right now, we are reviewing the submissions. My adviser insists that I am not qualified to review the papers because he designated me as a student organizer and my degree completion does not change that. But he expects me to write the reviews that were assigned to him! On top of that, he cannot cover my travel expenses for the workshop, because of the University policy not to pay expenses for the former students. So, I'm on my own to find the travel funding - I will need to ask my employer for funding.

What bothers me is that when convenient, I'm treated as a student (to write the reviews), but when not convenient, I am treated as a former student (funding the travel expenses). What should I do? I talked to him twice now, and I still getting emails asking when the reviews will done.

Is this a common practice? Am I out of the line to question it? And what does this say for our future relationship working independently in the same field.

I should say that I have a job and funding lined up (funding starts after the workshop). So, I don't need a letter of recommendation from my adviser, but staying on good terms would be beneficial. On the other hand, my adviser was hoping that I could fund some of his students over the next year with the funding I received.

Thank you!

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: @BillBarth This is in United States.

Comment: "Is this a common practice?"  More common than it should be, perhaps, but it is certainly not a standard practice.  "Am I out of the line to question it?"  Absolutely not.  "And what does this say for our future relationship working independently in the same field."  Good question.  I suggest calling him and having a conversation about this.  Don't pick up the phone until you're sure you can stay calm and cordial no matter what.  When you talk, work up to being as frank as you can, to the limits of his receptivity.  Try to make sure that he knows that your funding gives you some leverage here.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, I can understand a University not generally being able to pay for a non-employee's attendance at a remote event, but in my experience, there is always a way to make it work if some employee wants it done.

Comment: @Bill: Hmm, maybe I misunderstood.  I was interpreting the policy as "We can give funding to outside people so long as they are not former students."  Upon reflection, that is *so* ridiculous that your interpretation seems likely to be correct.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thank you for the sanity check. I will engage into the negotiations. The mentioned University policy is according to my adviser. I did not verify it. But I too find it curious, because you have some autonomy over your funding.

Comment: @Orion: You should look independently into what the funding policy is.  As a general rule, it is best to inquire into funding before you sign on to something requiring travel (although it is all too easy not to).  In my field we do not have "student organizers" so I don't know anything about the finer points of that.   But it is hard for me to read your situation in any other way than that you are being unfairly penalized for having graduated.  This is a really bad departmental practice, and it may well be worth discussing it with other faculty: the chair, the director of graduate studies...

Comment: _My adviser insists that I am not qualified to review the papers... But he expects me to write the reviews that were assigned to him._ — Repeat after me: "I'm sorry, but as you just said yourself, I'm not qualified to write your reviews."

Comment: It looks like your former adviser is being a bit of a xxxx... Has this been the case in the past? Are you concerned about him getting back at you if you refuse to do his job? Can he have a negative impact on your life/career?

Comment: @A.G. I am his first student to graduate. Not staying on his good side might have negative impact should I consider going for an academic position in the future. Something he very strongly encourages me to do and I haven't decided yet. My job is in a research lab and there he won't have negative influence. Then there are soft consequences, opportunities missed. He is obviously better connected in the field than I am, and animosity is not going to serve anyone.

Comment: @JeffE: I don't recommend that level of snark if OP wants to maintain a decent relationship with his former advisor.

Comment: @BillBarth no snark needed, but the point is well made - he should clearly ask the advisor to make up his mind; either he is qualified to write the reviews and sign them himself; or he isn't and shouldn't write them. The advisor can't have his cake and eat it too.

Comment: @BillBarth I don't think there's any chance of maintaining a decent relationship with this advisor. OP might be able to get recommendation letters from him, by agreeing to his abuse, but that's hardly "decent".

Comment: @Peteris, I agree, but there's a way to do it without dynamiting the bridge behind him. He's the advisor's first PhD student, clearly the advisor has some things to learn about working with former students and now colleagues. This can be a growing and learning experience for both of them, or everyone can end up bitter. I think OP has a choice as to how it goes.

Comment: I agree with @Peteris, it can be done carefully. My plan is to center the discussion on upgrading my role as an organizer, and defer any discussion about the reviews until we have the agreement on my official role. The discussion is motivated by the realization that it is very hard to ask my employer to fund the travel where I am representing the University. Then, I need to build up why it is in **my advisor's interest** to upgrade me: good for his reputation to have a student who already graduated, and frees him of the responsibility and liability - financial etc.

Comment: We can go from there. Once the role is set, then we can talk about responsibilities, including the reviews. I do not plan on agreeing to do the reviews without written conformation that my travel would be covered. If my role is upgraded, I'll gladly do reviews assigned to me, and will take care of my funding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Other cultures may have different approaches to the ethics of this, but I think it's pretty out of line for the US.

I would recommend standing by your commitment to help organize the workshop, but I would not do your former advisor's reviewing for him. You've graduated, you're a fully-fledged member of the doctoral community.

Pete's comment is pretty spot on. Be as nice and cordial as possible, but be firm in your refusal to do his work for him.

Comment: Removed incorrect "not". Just mentioning it, because it changes the whole sense of the sentence. +1 for "I would not do your former advisors reviewing for him."

Comment: _You've graduated, you're a fully-fledged member of the doctoral community._ — For the record, you were a fully-fledged member of the research community even before you graduated.  Otherwise, you wouldn't have landed a job.

Comment: I would only upvote this answer if there's also advice on HOW to refuse to do the work. That's the hard part. Of course OP knows that he shouldn't do the work that is not his.

Comment: Just to give an update. We had a conversation that stayed pretty civil, and at least the expectations are clear now. I will be upgraded to a regular organizer, and will be responsible for my own funding. He would not allow me to be a reviewer in order to maintain high-quality of the workshop and not bring any questions over the peer-review process credibility. I did not agree to do the reviews for him. I got a guilt trip for putting him in a very bad position. He would not have agreed to do the workshop had he known I wouldn't be reviewing the papers for him.

Comment: All said and done, I feel good about it. Not thrilled, but in peace with it. @Anh I structured the discussion over the roles and common interest: transitioning to the new phase of collaboration that is less day-to-day, but with more impact to his benefit. That I am willing to accept more responsibility for more independence, and that I am committed to organizing the workshop, and not putting him in a difficult position. Circling back to these points, whenever the conversation became tense, helped keep the tone cordial. At the end, we agreed to disagree.